# Can't select UIView when scrollView is zoomed in

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView inside a UIView. Inside the UIImageView I am adding a UIView (a pin) at runtime, so you can add the same UIView multiple times and reposition it.

The problem is the repositioning of the UIView when the UIImageView is zoomed in. I cannot get a hold of the UIView (pin) once the UIImageView/UIScrollView has zoommed in. The whole UIImageView/UIScrollView moves around but I can't get a hold of the pin. When the UIImageView is zoomed out I can still move the UIImageView around, but I can easily select and move the UIView.

Any idea on how to be able to select the UIView and not the UIImageView when I'm zoomed in?
Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    imageView_image.image = originalImage;
    scrollView.contentSize = self.view.frame.size;//originalImage.size;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 100.0;
}

- (IBAction)button_addAnnotation:(id)sender
{
    annotationImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"push-pin-mini@3x.png"]];
    [annotationImage setCenter:CGPointMake(imageView_image.bounds.size.width / 2, imageView_image.bounds.size.height / 2)];

    annotationImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    imageView_image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [annotationImage addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
    [imageView_image addSubview:annotationImage];
}


- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);

    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {

        CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:self.view];
        CGFloat magnitude = sqrtf((velocity.x * velocity.x) + (velocity.y * velocity.y));
        CGFloat slideMult = magnitude / 200;
        //NSLog(@"magnitude: %f, slideMult: %f", magnitude, slideMult);

        float slideFactor = 0.1 * slideMult; // Increase for more of a slide
        CGPoint finalPoint = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + (velocity.x * slideFactor),
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + (velocity.y * slideFactor));
        finalPoint.x = MIN(MAX(finalPoint.x, 0), self.view.bounds.size.width);
        finalPoint.y = MIN(MAX(finalPoint.y, 0), self.view.bounds.size.height);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:slideFactor*2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            recognizer.view.center = finalPoint;
        } completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You could probably make the pin's pan gesture recognizer take precedent over the map's pan gesture recognizer using something like 
`gestureRecognizer:shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:`

Comment: Awesome, that works. Wanna make the answer so I can mark it answered?

Comment: Oh, sure, I was starting to write out an answer anyway... You can let me know if our solutions differ. I'll post it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the scrollview not to pan while you attempt to move the pin, you can make the scrollview gesture fail using the `gestureRecognizer:shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:` delegate method, ex:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
        shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {

    // Make the scroll view pan fail if the pin's "panRecognizer"
    // is recognized
    if (gestureRecognizer == scrollView.panGestureRecognizer && 
        otherGestureRecognizer == panRecognizer) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I made it with this if statement, and it seems to work as well:     if ([otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]])

Comment: @TooManyEduardos Yeah, but since the pin's gesture recognizer is also a pan, that could get a bit dangerous... For example, hypothetically the pin pan could be the "otherGestureRecognizer" in which the scrollview gesture would be recognized instead. Since you're dealing with two pan gesture recognizers that's why I did the conditional this way... to be a bit more specific.

Comment: @TooManyEduardos But if it works for you then great! :) But if you notice any problems eventually, just keep in mind what I said. ;)